# Is a two variable function positive?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

For function $f(x,y)=4-8xy+y^2+2x^2y^2$ I have to prove that $f(x,y)>0$ for $0<x<1$ and $0<y<\frac{2}{3x}$. I think the function has a stationary point at $(0,0)$ which is out of the domain. I have also tried rewriting the expression $4-8xy+y^2+2x^2y^2$ as a sum of expressions using $(2-3xy),(2-3xy)^2,(1-x),(1-x)^2$,... which are all positive, but unsuccessfully.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to put in for $x$ any value $\in [0,1]$, then you will see. i.e. $x=0$, $x=0.5$, $x=1$

Comment: I did plot a graph in Mathematica, but I need a proof.

Answer (score 3):

Fix $y$ then think of $f_y(x) = 4-8xy+y^2+2x^2y^2$. Then $f_y'(x) = 4y(-2+xy)$  and $f_y'(x) < 0$ for $0<x<1$. Therefore $f_y(x)$ is monotonically decreasing for $0<x<1$. Similarly $f_x'(y) = -8x+2y+4x^2y$ and $f_{x=1}'(y) = -8+2y+4y < 0$ for $0<y<\frac{2}{3x}=2/3$. Therefore for all x, y $f(x,y) = f_y(x) > f_y(1) = f(1,y) = f_{x=1}(y) > f_{x=1}(2/3) = f(1, 2/3) = 0$.

Comment: Shouldn't $f_x'(y)$ be $-8x+2y+4x^2y$?

Comment: Yes you are correct, I'll edit it accordingly!